# How to ask for a specific part in MEF across several layers

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef

I have a solution with 3 layers

A

B

C

In layer C, I have the interface IRepository which has two implementations, RepositoryX and RepositoryY.

In layer B, I have the interface IController and in layer A I have a class named Foo. Now I know I can control which implementation of IRepository gets injected into a dependency by using a contract name or export metadata.

In an implementation of Controller, I am able to say I want RepositoryX or RepositoryY and that works.

In class Foo which is in layer A, I have a dependency for IController which gets injected. How can I control in class Foo which implementation of IRepository my IController will get?

I would be looking for something like:

```
class Foo  
{
    [Import("RepositoryX")]
    public IController MyController { get; set; }
```

Which would inject an IController which has itself a repository of type RepositoryX injected in the import property of the controller.

Is there a way to do this without having to define 2 controllers which are identical except for which type of Repository?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your implementation of `IController` defines which repository it uses with the appropriate `Import` attribute. Whether your implementation of `IController` uses `RepositoryX` or `RepositoryY` is known at compile time, and so importing `IController` will give you the `IController` implementation that uses the repository that was specified at compile time.

You can't ask for an `IController` implementation that uses the repository of you choice, but you can make the repository a property so you could import the repository you want in your `Foo` implementation and set it in your controller:

```
class Foo
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Foo(IController myController,
               [Import("RepositoryX")] IRepository repository)
    {
        myController.Repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it breaks my layer's encapsulation. For this to work I must have a reference in my highest layer A, to the interface defined in the data layer C. I guess if I follow the Dependency Inversion Principle my interface should be in layer B, but that's not my case.